# Parsing a "hierarchical" URL with regexes if there are splits in parsing logic

Tags: python, regex, url-parsing

Is there any way to adjust the remaining regex pattern to what have been already matched? A rough sketch to illustrate the idea:

```
          pattern
       /     |     \
      /      |      \
prefix1   prefix2   prefix3
   |         |         |
postfix1  postfix2  postfix3
```

This is a rather theoretical question; the practical application below is only for illustrative purposes.

I'm trying to find the first URLs to popular code hosting platforms, like github, gitlab etc., in a large text. The problem is, all platforms have different URL patterns:

```
github.com/<user>/<repo>
gitlab.com/<group1>/<group2>/.../<repo>
sourceforge.net/projects/<repo>
```

I can use lookbehind expressions, but then the expression gets really monstrous (Python re):

```
pattern = re.compile(
    r"(github\.com|bitbucket\.org|gitlab\.com|sourceforge\.net)/"
    # middle part - empty for all except sourceforge
    r"(?:(?<=github\.com/)|(?<=bitbucket\.org/)|(?<=gitlab\.com/)|"
    r"(?<=sourceforge\.net/)projects/)("
    # final part, the repository pattern
    r"(?<=github\.com/)[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+|"
    r"(?<=bitbucket\.org/)[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+|"
    r"(?<=gitlab\.com/)[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+(?:/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)+|"
    r"(?<=sourceforge\.net/projects/)[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+"
    r")")
```

Is there a more elegant way to do something like this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172920/discussion-on-question-by-marat-hierarchical-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way would probably be to rather use a custom parser and parse state-machine-style: first determine the site, then go a site-specific route:

```
patterns={
    'github.com': r'/(?P<user>[^/]+)/(?P<project>[^/#]+)(?:[/#]|$)',
    'sourceforge.net': r'/projects/(?P<project>)[^/]+/',
    <etc etc etc>
}

import urllib.parse
pr = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)

site = pr.hostname    # in case port is specified
parts = re.match(patterns[site], pr.path).groupdict()
```

Instead of regexes, paths can be parsed with a state machine, too, which would likely be more manageable if there are further splits ahead:
<sub>([they recommend a `enum` instead of magic strings for states](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365339/what-is-wrong-with-magic-strings); I used magic strings solely to simplify the example code)</sub>

```
def parse_github(path):
    r = argparse.Namespace()
    pp = path.split('/')
    p = pp.pop(0)
    assert(p == '')
    state='user'
    for p in pp:    # we dont need to backtrack in this case,
                    # so `for' is a fitting mechanism to iterate
                    # over the parts.
                    # if we needed to backtrack, we'd have to use
                    # an index variable or a stack or something
        if state=='user':
            r.user=p
            state='project'
        else if state=='project':
            r.project==p
            state='kind'
        else if state=='kind':
            if p in {'pull','commit','blob'}:
                state=p
            else: break  #end parsing, ignore anything that's left
        else if state=='pull':
            r.pr=p
            state='pr_tab'
        <etc etc>
    return r
```

---

In principle, there are no recursive constructs here, so this *can* be done solely with regexes, but this is very awkward:

```
site_patterns = [
    r"(github\.com/)[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+",
    r"(bitbucket\.org/)[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+",
    r"(gitlab\.com/)[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+(?:/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)+",
    r"(sourceforge\.net/projects/)[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+",
    <etc etc etc>
    ]
r_all = re.compile("("+"|".join(site_patterns)+")")   #good luck debugging this monster
```

Comment: Your previous comment was already informative enough, but there is even more to learn from the extended answer. Thank you!